# Bash filtering output when receiving input

Tags: bash, stream

I have a script which reads the output of a command using `while read`, and does minor tweaks (e.g. coloring, removing some lines). Sometimes, however, I get a line of the form:

`Would you like to hello world? (y/N):`

This line isn't completed (and thus, isn't displayed) until I enter input.

How do I modify this script to allow me to see these incomplete lines, on which I can then enter input?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to not use `while read`, since `read` only processes "complete" lines, i.e. lines that end with `LF`.
(Alternatively, `read` has an option `-d delim` which tells it to treat another delimiter as the end-of-line marker - in your case, this could be the question mark, or the `:` at the end of the prompt. However, I'll guess you can't use this in your particular case because you won't be able to predict when to use `-d`).

Depending on what exactly your script is doing, you might be able to pipeline the entire tweaking, e.g. through `sed`, `awk` and the likes.

For a more detailed answer, you'll need to post the innards of your current script.

Comment: Another non-standard option might be the `-t` option, to timeout and return whatever has been read so far. Tested with `read -t 1 bar < <(echo -n value)`, but that may be slightly different from your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

If you answer the prompts the same way all the time, and if the command reads from stdin (unlike ssh for instance), then you can

```
yes y | command | while read ...
```